# Quantity of transaction logs used per application/connection in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I would like to know the quantity of logs used (active logs) by each connection in the database.

I know how to retrieve the quantity of active logs for the database, but not for each application. Knowing the quantity of active logs in the database helps me to identify if a log-full condition is approaching.

However, I want to know which application is approaching to this condition of log-full. For this reason, I need to know how much log is used by each transaction (each application), but I have not found a view, snapshot or something else for each application.

Any ideas?

Comment: From the appearances of things like [this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301kline/0301kline.html), there doesn't appear to be separate logs per-application, there's one (set) for the whole db.  What do you mean by "application"?  How are you expecting the db to know an identifier?  There do appear to be some APIs to query log files (or tools using those)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logs are used by transactions (units of work), not connections, so -- something like this, may be?

```
select 
  application_handle, uow_log_space_used 
from 
  table(sysproc.mon_get_unit_of_work(null,null))
order by 2 desc
fetch first 5 rows only
```